# XCode does not use latest device support files

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

I have an old cordova app that a client still uses and I have an late 2014 mac, using monterrey 12.4. My XCode version is 13.4.1. From time to time, apple limits the version of the iOS SDK we can use to upload an app. Now the minimum is 16.4, my XCode is using 15.5. The solution to that was always use repos like this: https://github.com/iGhibli/iOS-DeviceSupport

I use their python script to unzip them at the correct path, which is /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform, or I do it manually(tried both). But my XCode simply does not recognize that there is most recent versions there(I have 16.4). Can anyone help me?

[image]